# Looking for widget that displays information

Tags: java, gwt

I am looking for widget, that displays text information next to for example TextBox, similar to the function setTitle(). 
Do you know something interesting in GWT?

Comment: Use `PopupPanel`, set position and show when one interacts with `TextBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you design your own using UIBinder. This lets you have the most controll over it and you can apoply custom CSS style to it.